# "Date" used as column name

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have a table called nexus.

One of the column name present is named 'date'

So when I try to write a select query with 'date' being in the where condition, it throws out an ERROR. This happens as 'date' is a reserved word for pl/sql.

I am not allowed to alter the column name as well.

```
select product from nexus where date = '20210621'
```

I am trying to extract 'product', using 'date' column in the where clause

date here is declared as a string datatype.

I tried using it as an alias and using "." (dot) operator, but nothing worked.

Is there any other way for this to work? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? For 5.6 and 8.0 it works just fine, but for being sure you can wrap `date` with ` character. Like this: `select product from nexus where \`date\` = '20210621'`

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) - study carefully.

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL or MySQL? `date` is an ANSI SQL and also Oracle reserved word, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. I.e. needs to be delimited as `"date"`.

Comment: Also, don't store dates in character columns. Use proper date data type instead.

Comment: This works fine in MySQL (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4a48e304fd77acc0dfce206c3e93edf).  I'm voting to close.

Comment: "It throws an error". Why don't you show us the error message? Why have us guess? It is unlikely that Oracle's programming language PL/SQL has anything to do with this either. In case you are using Oracle, you will have to use double quotes for the name. And then get upper/lower case right. It's probably "DATE" (i.e. all upper case) but it can be different. You see the correct spelling in Oracles `user_tab_cols` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned PL/SQL so I assume you are using Oracle. In Oracle, you can escape reserved names used as table name using double quotes:

```sql
select product from nexus where "date" = '20210621'
```

Each RDBMS has it's own method to escape - in MySQL it is usually a backtick (`), in SQL Server it is square braces ([]), etc.

```sql
--Oracle
select product from nexus where "date" = '20210621'

--MySQL
select product from nexus where `date` = '20210621'

--Sql Server
select product from nexus where [date] = '20210621'
```

These can be configured in some RDBMSs as well.

Comment: Yep. And the double quotes are the standard compliant deliimters for names, while brackets and backticks are propriatary to the DBMS in question. And in some (or all?) DBMS using delimiters on names makes the names case sensitive. In Oracle it is likely that "date" will fail while "DATE" will work. To make sure to get this right, we can check the column name in the user_tab_cols view that I already mentioned in the request comments.